# Property of dual generalized inequalities

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, geometric-inequalities, dual-cone

For $K$ a proper cone we define $x<_K y$ if and only if $y-x\in\text{int}K$. Denote $K^*$ as the dual cone of $K$ (also a proper cone). I would like to prove that $$x<_Ky\iff \lambda^T x<\lambda^T y \text{ for all } \lambda\in K^*-\{0\}.$$
This result is geometrically intuitive. I am able to rigorously prove the first direction:

Proof: Let $y-x\in\text{int}K$ and $\lambda\in K^*-\{0\}$. By definition of $K^*$, we have $\lambda^T(y-x)\ge 0$, so all we must show is that $\lambda^T(y-x)\ne 0$. Suppose the previous expression is $0$. As $y-x\in\text{int}K$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(y-x)\subseteq K$. We claim that $\exists v\in B_{\epsilon}(y-x)$ such that $\lambda^T v<0$, contradicting $\lambda\in K^*$. Indeed, $y-x\in\{v\vert \lambda^T v=0\}=\text{bd}(\{v\vert\lambda^Tv\ge 0\})$, thus $B_{\epsilon}(y-x)$ must contain points outside $\{v\vert\lambda^Tv\ge 0\}$ (since $\epsilon>0$. So the claim is proven and the result follows.

However, while geometrically intuitive, I am not able to rigorously prove the reverse direction. As an attempt, I proceeded by contradiction that $y-x\in K-\text{int}K\subseteq \text{bd}K$. To complete the proof is would be enough to show there is a nonzero $\lambda\in K^*$ such that $\lambda^T(y-x)=0$. Basically I want to prove (the forward direction of) the following: $$z\in\text{bd}K\iff \exists \lambda\in K^*-\{0\} \text{ s.t. } \lambda^T z=0.$$

Again, the picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is telling of why this is true, but a formal proof would be appreciated!

Comment: do you assume cone is convex ?

Comment: If your cone is not convex , then it is wrong take $K$ as the graph of $y=|x|$ in $R^2$

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying. I am assuming that the cone is closed, convex, has nonempty interior, and that it contains no line (i.e., is pointed). Would you be able to explain rigorously how to prove left to right (or both directions if possible)? When I say left to right I mean $z\in\text{bd}K$ implies there exists $\lambda\in K^*-\{0\}$ such that $\lambda^T z=0$ (i.e., right to left of the original problem). @Ashkan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now let assume $K$ is a convex closed cone. To prove right to left:

Let $a=y-x \in R^n$ such that $\lambda^t.a > 0$ for all $\lambda \in K^* - \{0\}$. Thus $a  \in K^{**} = K$ (Since $K$ is convex and closed cone). We only need to show that $a \in \text{int}K$. To this end, let $\delta=\inf\{\lambda^t.a ~; \quad  \lambda \in K^*,~ \| \lambda \| =1 \}$; note that $\delta > 0$. We show that $B(a;\varepsilon) \subseteq K^{**}=K$ where $\varepsilon < \delta$. Pick $x=a+\varepsilon b \in B(a;\varepsilon)$ where $\|b\| \leq 1.$ Now let $\lambda \in K^{*} $ with $\| \lambda \| =1$. Then we have $$ \langle \lambda , x \rangle =\langle \lambda , a + \varepsilon b \rangle=\langle \lambda , a \rangle + \varepsilon \langle \lambda , b \rangle \ge \delta - \varepsilon  > 0   $$

Therefore $x \in K^{**} = K.$

Comment: Thanks very much!! My only question is why is $\delta>0$? @Ashkan

Comment: @Atsana  since the infimum is attained . inner product is continuous function over the compact set $\{ \lambda : ~ \lambda \in K^* , ~ \| \lambda \| =1   \}$

Comment: Oh are you saying that it is because compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ always contain their infimum? So the infimum of $\{\lambda^T a; \lambda\in K^*,||\lambda||=1\}$ is actually equal to $\lambda_*^T a$ for some $\lambda_*\in K^*$, $||\lambda_*||=1$? So it's actually attained. @Ashkan

Comment: I am saying this :
Let $f(x)= \langle a,x\rangle$ and $M=\{ \lambda : ~ \lambda \in K^* , ~ \| \lambda \| =1   \} \subseteq R^n$   then $M  $ is compact. and  we know that $f$ is continuous and positive on $M$ so its minimum value is positive on $M$

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ is not convex then Right to Left  is wrong. Take $$K= \text{graph of}  ~y=|x| ~\cup ~X-\text{axis}$$ Then $K^* = \{(x,y) : x=0,~ y\ge 0 \}$

Now take $x=0 , y=(1,1)$ Then Right side is satisfied but $y-x=y \notin int K$